# Match rows from 2 table and update value of 1 column from 1 table to the other table if the value in the corresponding column is null

Tags: sql, oracle, datatable, insert, procedure

I have two tables as followed:

Table A (with Column 1A and Column 2A)
Table B (with Column 1B and Column 2B)

I want to write a procedure that helps me do the following:

1. Find matched rows of Table A and Table B, where 1A = 1B
2. After that, for each of the matched rows, if 2B is null, then update it with 2A; if it is not null, then not update it.

I am a newbie in SQL and Oracle, I would appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_B B
USING (SELECT 1A, 2A FROM TABLEA) A
ON (A.1A = B.1B)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
SET B.2B = COALESCE(B.2B, A.2A);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and actually for the USING it says that ON is missing

Comment: If that answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE TABLEA A 
SET A.2A = (
                            SELECT 2B
                            FROM   B
                            WHERE  B.1B= A.1A
            )
WHERE A.2A IS NULL;

this is what worked for me! Thanks for all the inputs guys!